# ExtJS - localStorage

Tags: extjs4, local-storage

I have 'Movie' model and hold data in Ext.data.Store. Movies are displayed in gridPanel. After giving search param and clicking button store is reloading.

Now, I'm trying to use localStorage. It rather should save data inside function of listener:

```
listeners: {
                'click': function() {
                    movieDataStore.sync();
                    var textValue = Ext.getCmp("searchFieldId").getValue();

                    movieDataStore.load({
                        params : {
                            start : 0,
                            limit : 25,
                            t : textValue
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

How should I make it?

---

UPDATE V1

If I would use Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider should I initialize cache variable like this:

```
        var movieLocalCacheStore = Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider.create(); 

    var movieGridPanel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store : movieDataStore,

        tbar : [ 'Search', {
            xtype : 'textfield',
            name : 'searchField',
            id: 'searchFieldId',
            emptyText : 'Put movie title here',
            hideLabel : true,
            width : 200
        }, {
            xtype : 'button',
            text : 'Search',
            tooltip : 'Search for movie',
            listeners: {
                'click': function() {
                    var textValue = Ext.getCmp("searchFieldId").getValue();

                    movieDataStore.load({
                        params : {
                            start : 0,
                            limit : 25,
                            t : textValue
                        }
                    });
                    movieDataStore.sync();
                    movieGridPanel.getView().refresh();

                    //localStorage.setItem(textValue, movieDataStore.getAt(0));
                    movieLocalCacheStore.set(textValue, movieDataStore.getAt(0));

                }
            }
        } ]
    });
```

?

I have a model named 'MovieModel'. Is it `movieDataStore.getAt(0)` correct way to get object?

How should I check if there is cached search results (and load to movieDataStore/movieGridPanel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by using localStorage variable:

```
var textValue = Ext.getCmp("searchFieldId").getValue();                 

    var tmpRecord = localStorage.getItem(textValue);
    if(tmpRecord != null) {
                 ...
    } else {
        var movieRecord = {
                title : data.Title,
                year : data.Year,
                genre : data.Genre,
                plot : data.Plot,
                poster : data.Poster
            };

        localStorage.setItem(textValue, JSON.stringify(movieRecord));
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an instance of the local storage by calling the static create method. Here is how you can do it:

```
var myLocalStore = Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider.create();
```

You can store and retrieve the values using [set](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider-method-set) and [get](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider-method-get) methods. Here is an example:

```
myLocalStore.set('srhTxt',value);
```

If you have many parameters you can combine them into an object and store as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Abdel Olakara for explaination. I've putted my updated source code using `LocalStorageProvider`